# MySQL ASP.NET MVC in Monodevelop

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, monodevelop

Hi guys I am new really new to ASP.NET MVC and I am using Mono develop on Linux Mint to do it. I am trying to connect to a MySQL server on my computer through the MySqlConnection object. When I try using this object it gives me the error

```
The type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly 'System.Data,Version=4.0.0.0,culture=neutral PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

so I go into Project->Add Nuget Packages and try to install the package System.Data.Common but that gives me that error:

```
Adding System.Data.Common...
The 'System.Data.Common 4.1.0' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.7.0'.
```

After that I try going into one of my Web.config files and adding it there.

```
<assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
```

But still nothing even after restoring the packages.Here is my C# class file I am trying to use it in. It is not complete but before I would include more code I wish to resolve this error.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
//using System.Data.Common;

namespace FairOrderingSystem
{

    public class MySQLdatabase{
        public MySQLdatabase(){

        }
        private void test(){
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection ();
            connection.ConnectionString = 
                "Data Source = localhost;" +
                "Initial Catalog=fair;" +
                "User id=shane;" +
                "Password=Gaming12;";
            connection.Open ();
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by right-clicking on the "References" line in the Solution toolbar, selecting "Edit References..." and adding System.Data from the Assembly list.